# Vectorize iterative addition in NumPy arrays

Tags: python, loops, numpy, optimization, vectorization

For each element in a randomized array of 2D indices (with potential duplicates), I want to "+=1" to the corresponding grid in a 2D zero array. However, I don't know how to optimize the computation. Using the standard for loop, as shown here,

```
def interadd():
    U = 100 
    input = np.random.random(size=(5000,2)) * U
    idx = np.floor(input).astype(np.int) 

    grids = np.zeros((U,U))      
    for i in range(len(input)):
        grids[idx[i,0],idx[i,1]] += 1
    return grids
```

The runtime can be quite significant:

```
>> timeit(interadd, number=5000)
43.69953393936157
```

Is there a way to vectorize this iterative process?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could speed it up a little by using [`np.add.at`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.at.html), which correctly handles the case of duplicate indices:

```
def interadd(U, idx):
    grids = np.zeros((U,U))      
    for i in range(len(idx)):
        grids[idx[i,0],idx[i,1]] += 1
    return grids

def interadd2(U, idx):
    grids = np.zeros((U,U))
    np.add.at(grids, idx.T.tolist(), 1)
    return grids

def interadd3(U, idx):
    # YXD suggestion
    grids = np.zeros((U,U))
    np.add.at(grids, (idx[:,0], idx[:,1]), 1)
    return grids
```

which gives

```
>>> U = 100
>>> idx = np.floor(np.random.random(size=(5000,2))*U).astype(np.int)
>>> (interadd(U, idx) == interadd2(U, idx)).all()
True
>>> %timeit interadd(U, idx)
100 loops, best of 3: 8.48 ms per loop
>>> %timeit interadd2(U, idx)
100 loops, best of 3: 2.62 ms per loop
```

---

And YXD's suggestion:

```
>>> (interadd(U, idx) == interadd3(U, idx)).all()
True
>>> %timeit interadd3(U, idx)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.09 ms per loop
```

Comment: Was typing almost the same thing.You can change `idx.T.tolist()` to `(idx[:, 0], idx[:, 1])`, should be faster still.

Answer (score 6):

Divakar's answer lead me to try the following, which looks to be the fastest method yet:

```
lin_idx = idx[:,0]*U + idx[:,1]
grids = np.bincount(lin_idx, minlength=U**2).reshape(U, U)
```

Timings:

```
In [184]: U = 100 
     ...: input = np.random.random(size=(5000,2)) * U
     ...: idx = np.floor(input).astype(np.int)

In [185]: %timeit interadd3(U, idx)  # By DSM / XYD
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.68 ms per loop

In [186]: %timeit unique_counts(U, idx)  # By Divakar
1000 loops, best of 3: 676 µs per loop

In [187]: %%timeit
     ...: lin_idx = idx[:,0]*U + idx[:,1]
     ...: grids = np.bincount(lin_idx, minlength=U*U).reshape(U, U)
     ...: 
10000 loops, best of 3: 97.5 µs per loop
```

Comment: Huge improvement it seems!

Answer (score 5):

You can convert `R,C` indices from `idx` to linear indices, then find out the unique ones alongwith their counts and finally store them in the output `grids` as the final output. Here's the implementation to achieve the same -

```
# Calculate linear indices corressponding to idx
lin_idx = idx[:,0]*U + idx[:,1]

# Get unique linear indices and their counts
unq_lin_idx,idx_counts = np.unique(lin_idx,return_counts=True)

# Setup output array and store index counts in raveled/flattened version
grids = np.zeros((U,U))  
grids.ravel()[unq_lin_idx] = idx_counts
```

Runtime tests -

Here are the runtime tests covering all the approaches (including [@DSM's approaches](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31094448/3293881)) and using the same definitions as listed in that solution -

```
In [63]: U = 100
    ...: idx = np.floor(np.random.random(size=(5000,2))*U).astype(np.int)
    ...: 

In [64]: %timeit interadd(U, idx)
100 loops, best of 3: 7.57 ms per loop

In [65]: %timeit interadd2(U, idx)
100 loops, best of 3: 2.59 ms per loop

In [66]: %timeit interadd3(U, idx)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.24 ms per loop

In [67]: def unique_counts(U, idx):
    ...:     lin_idx = idx[:,0]*U + idx[:,1]
    ...:     unq_lin_idx,idx_counts = np.unique(lin_idx,return_counts=True)
    ...:     grids = np.zeros((U,U))  
    ...:     grids.ravel()[unq_lin_idx] = idx_counts
    ...:     return grids
    ...: 

In [68]: %timeit unique_counts(U, idx)
1000 loops, best of 3: 595 µs per loop
```

Runtimes suggest that the proposed `np.unique` based approach is more than 50% faster than the second fastest approach.

Comment: `np.unique` uses sorting under the hood, so has worse time complexity than `np.add.at`, but on the other hand your approach has a faster memory access pattern for the `grids` array.

Comment: @moarningsun Yeah I think it uses `sorting` and `differentiation` under the hood. That makes sense I guess on that faster runtimes. Would be interesting to find out what's going underneath with `add.at`.

Comment: This made me think of an interesting approach: `grids = np.bincount(lin_idx, minlength=U**2).reshape(U, U)`

Comment: @moarningsun `bincount` is surely another way to look at `add.at` and probably might be faster. Post a solution with it and see if the timings are better with it?